# How to create a FloatBuffer dynamically

Tags: java, nio

I have need to create FloatBuffer's from a dynamic set of floats (that is, I don't know the length ahead of time). The only way I've found to do this is rather inelegant (below). I assume I'm missing something and there must be a cleaner/simpler method.

My solution:

```
Vector<Float> temp = new Vector<Float>();
//add stuff to temp
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect( work.size() * 4/*sizeof(float)*/ );
bb.order( ByteOrder.nativeOrder() );
FloatBuffer floatBuf = bb.asFloatBuffer();
for( Float f : work )
    floatBuf.put( f );
floatBuf.position(0);
```

I am using my buffers for OpenGL commands thus I need to keep them around (that is, the resulting FloatBuffer is not just a temporary space).

Answer (score 5):

If you're using the OpenGL API through Java, I assume you're using LWJGL as the go-between. If so, there's a simple solution for this, which is to use the `BufferUtils` class in the org.lwjgl package. The method `BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer()` allows you to put in `float`s from an `array`, which if you're using a `Vector`, is a simple conversion. Although it's not much better than your method, it does save the need for a byte buffer which is nasty enough, and allows for a few quick conversions. The code for this exists in the new LWJGL tutorials for OpenGL 3.2+ [here](http://lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=The_Quad_with_DrawArrays).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a plain ByteBuffer and I would write out the data when the buffer fills. (or do what ever you planed to do with it)

e.g.

```
SocketChannel sc = ...
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(32 * 1024).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
for(int i = 0 ; i < 100000000; i++) {
   float f = i;
   // move to a checkFree(4) method.
   if (bb.remaining() < 4) {
       bb.flip();
       while(bb.remaining() > 0)
           sc.write(bb);
   }
   // end of method
   bb.putFloat(f);
```

}

Creating really large buffers can actually be slower than processing the data as you generate it.

Note: this creates almost no garbage. There is only one object which is the ByteBuffer.

Comment: I amended the question. I need to keep the FloatBuffer's around, thus ideally they should not be too large (as I will have many), and I won't be reusing them (too much).

Comment: What is their end purpose?  Instead of using a `Vector<Float>` can you use `TFloatArrayList` http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/list/array/TFloatArrayList.html

Comment: The OpenGL API requires a FloatBuffer (or other Buffer types) for its function parameters. That is, I provide them to the API.

Comment: Can you make repeated calls for a relatively limited size FloatBuffer? This way you could reuse the same fixed size buffer of say 1024 float values. (You can always make a FloatBuffer shorter)

Comment: No. I need to keep all (or at least several) of the buffers around for repeated calls to the API. That is, I cannot just reuse one large enough FloatBuffer.

Comment: Something worth remembering is that off heap memory is only allocated by the OS as it is used.  If you create a 10 MB direct FloatBuffer but only use 4 KB, it will use 10 MB of *virtual* memory but only 4 KB of main memory.  If you have a 64-bit JVM you may find you can create large buffers on the assumption they won't really be used and avoid having to worry about how large really they are.